Quantum Circuit inside Gate
Is there a trick that allows me to put a quantum circuit inside a gate with quantikz?
My attempt so far is to use \includegraphics{<img>} to put an image inside the gate:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{\ket{\psi}} & & \gate[2,disable auto height]{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{qtp.png}} \\
    \lstick{\ket{\Phi^+}} & \qwbundle{2} & &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}

This works, but it would be convenient to be able to edit the circuit inside the gate in the same document as the "outer" circuit.
Simply adding the circuit inside the gate \gate[2]{\begin{quantikz}...\end{quantikz}} doesn't seem to work.
Here is the circuit for the circuit inside the gate:
\begin{quantikz}
    & \ctrl{1}  & \gate{H} & & \meter{} \\
    & \targ{} & & \meter{} \\
    & & & \gate{X} \wire[u][1]{c} & \gate{Z} \wire[u][2]{c} &
\end{quantikz}

